# Java Regexp "\\d+" (Digits Only) not working

Tags: java, regex

Input string: `07-000`

JAVA Regexp: `\\d+`  (digits only)

Expected Result: `07000`  (digits only from input string)

Then why does this Java code return `07` only?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("07-000");

String result = null;
if (matcher.find()) {
    result = matcher.group();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Why would matcher.find only match "one" "set" of numbers? Where is that in the documentation? And what is a "set"??

Comment: The documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find() . `find` stops at the last character that matches the pattern.

Comment: thank you Riaz and svasa, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then why does this Java code return 07 only?

It returns only `07` because that is the first group found by your regex, you need a while loop to get all groups and later you can concatenate them to get all numbers in one string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("07-000");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (matcher.find()) 
{
     sb.append( matcher.group() );
}

System.out.println( "All the numbers are : " +  sb.toString() );
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you want to achieve is rather this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("07-000");

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
// Iterate over all the matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Append the new match to the current result
    result.append(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
07000
```

Indeed [`matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) will return the next subsequence in the input that matches with the pattern so if you call it only once, you will get only the first subsequence which is `07` here. So if you want to get everything you need to loop until it returns `false` indicating that there is no more matches available.

However in this particular case, it would be better to call directly `myString.replaceAll("\\D+", "")` which will replace by an empty `String` any non digit characters.